# how to fix my dialog dim and alpha effects

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want my android dialog to look something like:

[image]

but using this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:alpha="0.20"
    android:backgroundDimAmount="0.0">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/socialBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        android:text="@string/fb_share" />
```

leads to this dialog:

[image]

problems:

(1) the buttons should have alpha=1, but seems with alpha 0.2

(2) the dialog bg should have alpha=0.2, but seems with alpha 1

(3) the bg surrounding should be with dim=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set background image or color to get the desired effect you are looking for.

For example if using color, then the translucent background for dialog can be achieved by adding below line in the Linearlayout properties.

```
android:background="#B2000000"
```

The first 2 digits decide the transparency effect. 
The format is **#AARRGGBB**, where AA is the alpha channel, RR is the red channel, GG is the green channel and BB is the blue channel. To calculate AA multiply %Opacity with 255. For example for 30% transparency i.e 70% opacity : `255 * 0.7 = 178`, in hex B2. So for black translucent background the color comes to #B2000000

Similarly to have solid button color either set color or your custom background image.

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_button_bg"
```

Comment: how about the non-translucent bg? I want the surrounding be clear

Comment: @EladBenda: I am assuming by surrounding you still mean the area inside the dialog box i.e. surrounding the buttons. If yes, then to remove translucency in above example remove AA from the #AARRGGBB, so for black opaque background it becomes android:background="#000000".

Answer (score 3):

**(1) the buttons should have alpha=1, but seems with alpha 0.2**

That is default button background. You have to give specific background using `android:background` property of button.And I don't think `android:src="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"` works for buttons. That property is used for `ImageView`.

**(2) the dialog bg should have alpha=0.2, but seems with alpha 1**

Are you sure the alpha value is 0.2 for the dialog background? By looking at the design, I guess alpha value should be `0.7 - 0.8` which results is partial transparency.And also you are setting only alpha. You need to specify background color also.I suggest giving alpha values dynamically using `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable` method.

Example :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
d.setAlpha(178); //alpha 0.7 (0-250 range)
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
dialog.show();
```

dialog layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:backgroundDimAmount="0.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/socialBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#0066FF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="  Facebook  " />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

results in following dialog

[image]

Comment: i cannot understand: how can i make the dialog background partial-transparent? nowadays the only buttons became partial-transparent and these are the only ones I want to stay with full opacity

Comment: As I said give alpha dynamically using `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable` method and give specific color/drawable to `Button` using `android:background` property.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Dialog mdialog =new Dialog(this);
Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
d.setAlpha(55);
mdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```